# Update all rows for one column in a table with data in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I appreciate any advice on this..

I have two tables where I have to update a column in my primary table with data that resides in another secondary table.  I cannot rely on views, etc as this data has to be able to be edited by the user in APEX in the future.  I am basically pre-populating the data for the users to reduce their manual entry.

Primary Table = `Table 1`

Secondary Table = `Table 2`

Columns to be updated in `Table 1`  = `FTE_ID`, `ACCOUNT_TYPE`

Columns where the data will come from `Table 2` = `R_ID`, `ACCOUNT_TYPE`

Common column in both tables = `TABLE1.FID` AND `TABLE2.FID`

Here is what I have tried, but I get "single-row subquery returns more than one row" because there are multiple `table1.fid` rows in `table1`.  I basically want to perform this update for ALL rows where `TABLE1.FID = TABLE2.FID`.

Here is my attempt:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET TABLE1.FTE_ID = 
(SELECT TABLE2.R_ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.FID = TABLE2.FID);
```

Error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the proximate problem by using aggregation or row number:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET TABLE1.FTE_ID = (SELECT MAX(TABLE2.R_ID)
                         FROM TABLE2
                         WHERE TABLE1.FID = TABLE2.FID
                        );
```

The subquery can only return one row; it is an "arbitrary" value from the possible matching values.

If the field is a character field and you want all matching values, then perhaps `listagg` is more appropriate:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET TABLE1.FTE_ID = (SELECT LISTAGG(t2.R_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.R_ID)
                         FROM TABLE2 t2
                         WHERE TABLE1.FID = t2.FID
                        );
```

Comment: This actually made me realize the actual issue which is that I have duplicates in BOTH tables, hence your listagg solution.  Brilliant!  I am testing my new (modified) table now.  Thank You